# Can't redirect stdin to another process and have that process answer back correctly

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin, fifo

I have a project to do in C where I have to make a game where 2 clients talk with a server, and that server handles the plays, and then responds to each of them, one at the time, until the game is finished.
I'm doing this for weeks now and I managed to do something like:

1. Server has a fork somewhere where the child, exec() a game (supplied by me) and I redirect that output to the client (very crudely I might add ...), and an unnamed pipe for speaking with his parent.
2. The client receives that output, sees the game board and sends a play to the server.
3. The parent uses the other end of the unnamed pipe to receive what the client sent and sends it to the child.

As soon as the first play is done, the server enters in a loop of "invalid plays" but I don't send anything. What is going on? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Restrictions of this project are that we can only use pipes and fifos (not threads or sockets) and open, close, read and write. Only printfs allowed on the game.c code.

Example of a run:

Open server with `./server`, open client with `./client John`. In client, type `1` and enter. Then type `1 1` and enter to make a play. Then, the error occurs.

#### client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int fdfifo_CS, fdfifo_SC, fd, conta;
char buffer[400];
int num=0;  

fdfifo_CS = open("fifo_publico_cliente_servidor", O_WRONLY);        

fdfifo_SC = open("fifo_privado_servidor_cliente", O_RDONLY);

write(fdfifo_CS, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])+1);               

while(1)
{
    num = read(fdfifo_SC,buffer,sizeof(buffer)); 
        write(1,buffer,num);

    num = read(0,buffer,sizeof(buffer));        
        write(fdfifo_CS, buffer, num);

    num = read(0,buffer,sizeof(buffer));        
        write(fdfifo_CS, buffer, num);
}
```

#### server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int fdfifo_CS, fdfifo_SC, num=0, pid=0, fd, pipefd[2];
char buffer[1024];

write(1, "\nServer ON !\n", strlen("\nServer ON !\n"));

mkfifo("fifo_publico_cliente_servidor",0777);

fdfifo_CS = open("fifo_publico_cliente_servidor", O_RDWR);  

mkfifo("fifo_privado_servidor_cliente",0777);

fdfifo_SC = open("fifo_privado_servidor_cliente", O_WRONLY);

num = read(fdfifo_CS,&buffer,sizeof(buffer));

do
{
    write(fdfifo_SC,"\n\n!!! Menu !!!\n", strlen("\n\n!!! Menu !!!\n"));
    write(fdfifo_SC,"----------------------------------------------\n", strlen("----------------------------------------------\n"));
    write(fdfifo_SC,"1) Play.\n", strlen("1) Play.\n"));

    write(fdfifo_SC,"Choose: ", strlen("Choose: "));

    read(fdfifo_CS,buffer,sizeof(buffer));

    switch(buffer[0])
    {
        case '1':

                    pipe(pipefd);

                    pid = fork();
                    if (pid == 0) 
                    {
                        fd = open("/dev/pts/8", O_RDWR, 0777); //To redirect to the bash of the client used. Must be changed to the correct tty.
                            dup2(fd,1);
                            close(fd);

                        close(pipefd[1]);
                        dup2(pipefd[0],0);
                        close(pipefd[0]);

                        execl("game","game",(char*) NULL);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        close(pipefd[0]); 

                        num = read(fdfifo_CS, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                            write(pipefd[1], buffer, num);

                        close(pipefd[1]);

                    }

                break;

        default:
            printf("DONE");
            break;
    }
    }while(1);
}
```

#### game.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_table(char *p, char t[3][3]) {
    printf("\nO:%s:  %c|%c|%c\n", p, '1', '2', '3');
    printf("O:%s:1 %c|%c|%c\n", p, t[0][0], t[0][1], t[0][2]);
    printf("O:%s:  -+-+-\n", p);
    printf("O:%s:2 %c|%c|%c\n", p, t[1][0], t[1][1], t[1][2]);
    printf("O:%s:  -+-+-\n", p);
    printf("O:%s:3 %c|%c|%c\n\n", p, t[2][0], t[2][1], t[2][2]);
}

/* check if this was a winning play */
int winning_play(int x, int y, char t[3][3]) {
    int v = t[y-1][x-1];
    if (t[y-1][0] == v && t[y-1][1] == v && t[y-1][2] == v)
            return 1;
    if (t[0][x-1] == v && t[1][x-1] == v && t[2][x-1] == v)
            return 1;
    if ((x + y % 2 == 0 && /* part of a diagonal */
        t[0][0] == v && t[1][1] == v && t[2][2] == v) ||
        (t[0][2] == v && t[1][1] == v && t[2][0] == v))
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char table[3][3] = 
        { {' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '} };
    char play[16];
    int stop = 0, win = 0, turn = 1, turns = 0;
    do {
        int x, y, check;
        /* display table to both players */
        print_table("12", table);
        turn = (turn + 1) % 2;
        turns++;
        do {
            /* display message to the current player */
            printf("OUT:%d: play (format \"x y\")?\n", turn+1);
            /* ask for input from current player */
            printf("IN:%d\n", turn+1);
            fgets(play, sizeof(play), stdin);
            check = (sscanf(play, "%d%d", &x, &y) == 2 &&
                x >= 1 && x <=3 && y >= 1 && y <= 3 &&
                table[y-1][x-1] == ' ');
            if (check == 0)
                /* display message to current player */
                printf("OUT:%d: invalid play\n", turn+1);
        } while (!check);
        table[y-1][x-1] = (turn == 0 ? 'X' : 'O');
        win = winning_play(x, y, table);
        stop = (turns == 9);
    } while (!stop && !win);
    /* display final table to both players */
    print_table("12", table);
    /* display final score to both players */
    if (win)
        printf("RES:12: winner %d\n", turn+1);
    else
        printf("RES:12: draw\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) In particular you can't just dump your whole assignment and expect someone else to debug it all for you. Surely you can use a debugger and/or debug print statements to trace the program more to get closer to the cause of the problem first.

Comment: It is always worth checking the return values provided by library functions you call. Especially I/O functions.

Comment: "the server enter in a loop". That is likely caused by the `scanf` failing. And that is likely caused by unexpected data in the input stream. The obvious thing for you to do is to put a break point at that line of code and examine what the result of the `scanf` is.

Comment: I looks as if you are trying to use indexing variables in the range `1..` and adjust them to index the arrays. Far better to accept that the range `0..` is good for computers, and adjust that for human input/output at the interface.

Comment: Why isn't code checking the return value of `fgets(play, sizeof(play), stdin);`?

Comment: In java i did debug all the time and that was awesome and super easy to do, but in C, i have no idea how to use gdb.

Comment: The code of the game.c can't be changed, its like that by definition and we have to work with it "as is".

Comment: I recommend you to use printf and rubber duck code until you find a mistake. And then you come here to ask for help.

Comment: Is the game Tic Tac Toe (aka Noughts and Crosses)?  If so, say so — it lets people know what to expect.

Comment: Also, if you're working on Windows, then maybe `void main()` is OK.  If you're working on any other platform, `void main()` is bogus.  Since you include a header from a `linux` subdirectory, your use of `void main()` is wrong in all three programs.  And you need to turn up the compiler warnings so it complains about it and refuses to compile the code, then fix it and all the other warnings so it does compile.  Start with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` and progress from there.  Add `-std=c11` if you're not using GCC 5.x or later.

Comment: Hello all. printf doesnt seem to show anything besides \n. I'll research on this rubber duck code. I'm working on linux.